# JqueryUI draggable not triggering stop event when object is in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, iframe

Please see my example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Msd7v/10/

```
console.log($('#app').contents().find('.widget').draggable({
  iframeFix:true,
  start:function(){ console.log('started') },
  drag:function(){ console.log('dragging') },
  stop:function(){ console.log('stopped') }
}));​
```

You can see in the console when dragging an item, that it will trigger the start and drag events, but if you let go, the stop action will not trigger.  You also cannot drag that item again, presumably because the mouseup state was not properly handled.

Anyone have some ideas for a fix?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added new example without srcdoc to show this happens in a working iframe.

Answer (score 0):

None of the major browsers support the srcdoc attribute which I assume is why it's not functioning correctly: http://w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

Comment: This error happens with a real iframe, the behavior is the same as using srcdoc in jsfiddle (srcdoc works in chrome).  Had to make a simple example, that was the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jsfiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Msd7v/30/

Updating jQuery to 1.10.1 and jquery-ui to 1.10.3 fixes this